# Python multiprocessing - reassigning jobs dynamically from pool - without async?

Tags: python, synchronization, multiprocessing, pool

So I have a batch of 1000 tasks that I assign using parmap/python multiprocessing module to 8 cores (dual xeon machine 16 physical cores). Currently this runs using synchronized.

The issue is that usually 1 of the cores lags well behind the other cores and still has several jobs/tasks to complete after all the other cores  finished their work. This may be related to core speed (older computer) but more likely due to some of the tasks being more difficult than others - so the 1 core that gets the slightly more difficult jobs gets laggy...

I'm a little confused here - but is this what asynch parallelization does?  I've tried using it before, but because this step is part of a very large processing step - it wasn't clear how to create a barrier to force the program to wait until all async processes are done.

Any advice/links to similar questions/answers are appreciated.

[EDIT] To clarify, the processes are ok to run independently, they all save data to disk and do not share variables.

Answer (score 2):

*parmap author here*

By default, both in multiprocessing and in parmap, tasks are divided in chunks and chunks are sent to each multiprocessing process (see the [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map)). The reason behind this is that sending tasks individually to a process would introduce significant computational overhead in many situations. The overhead is reduced if several tasks are sent at once, in chunks.

The number of tasks on each chunk is controlled with `chunksize` in multiprocessing (and `pm_chunksize` in parmap). By default, `chunksize` is computed as `"number of tasks"/(4*"pool size")`, rounded up (see the [multiprocessing source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/74d7f76e2c953fbfdb7ce01b7319d91d471cc5ef/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L478])). So for your case, 1000/(4*4) = 62.5 -> 63 tasks per chunk.

If, as in your case, many computationally expensive tasks fall into the same chunk, that chunk will take a long time to finish.

One "cheap and easy" way to workaround this is to pass a smaller `chunksize` value. Note that using the extreme `chunksize=1` may introduce undesired larger cpu overhead.

A proper queuing system as suggested in other answers is a better solution on the long term, but maybe an overkill for a one-time problem.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look at creating microservices and using a queue pool.  For instance, you could put a list of jobs in celery or redis, and then have the microservices pull from the queue one at a time and process the job.  Once done they pull the next item and so forth.  That way your load is distributed based on readiness, and not based on a preset list.

http://www.celeryproject.org/

https://www.fullstackpython.com/task-queues.html

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it is the right direction to investigate. Just seems these tools are overkill for my application that doesn't involve web deployment or cloud. Maybe one of the smaller task-queuing tools might be simpler to use?!

Comment: You can build simple ones.  The nice things about these types of projects, if you write code to be a tool, once you are done, you will begin to find usages in a ton of different projects.  You will find that what seems like overkill in one project is a lifesaver in another.

Comment: Ok, so it seems this is not the right solution; technically multiprocessing module should do what I was looking for.

Comment: Async allows an application that is waiting for IO to move on in the process, CPU bound computations are still synchronous, but when you are mostly waiting for data from IO, asynch becomes a massive speed upgrade since it can open 100's of connections simultaneously and allow you to process them as the data comes in.